# Get all the days of sundays in a month using mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading

like for example.

this month is December 2012 and as we know all the sundays in this month of 2012 are  2,9,16,23,30.

can anyone please tell me how to get all the days of sundays like as shown below in a month using mysql query?

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _
|  Sundays  |
|- - - - - -| 
|    2      |
|    9      |
|    16     |
|    23     |
|    30     |
 - - - - - -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Here is a SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4715)

```
select DATE_ADD('2012-12-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY) as Date,
row+1  as DayOfMonth from

(
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row FROM 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 
        union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) t1,
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 
        union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) t2, 
(SELECT @row:=-1) t3 limit 31
) b
where 
DATE_ADD('2012-12-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY)
between '2012-12-01' and '2012-12-31'
and
DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD('2012-12-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY))=1
```